# Putting Laravel and Lumen controllers inside packages

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm developing a package which has controllers in it and I want this package to be compatible with (or useable by) both Laravel and Lumen projects. My problem is Laravel controllers extend `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` and Lumen controllers extend `Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller`. The controller inside my package can't extend them both.

The only solution I've come up with is to have the controllers inside the package extend `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`.

But I see some problems:

1. `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` should exist; which means it wouldn't work if the `App` namespace is named differently.
2. The package is now "aware" that it is being included in something.
3. Testability: I can't test the controller independently because of the reference to `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`.

Is there a better way of doing this?

**Edit 1**

I'm finding other classes which are affected in a similar way. For example, the namespace of the trait `Authorizable` is `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access` in Laravel while it is `Laravel\Lumen\Auth` in Lumen. I am using a model which uses that trait. How do I make my model compatible with both Lumen and Laravel?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could simply have two different files and classes wrapped in if statements and check for the corresponding classes to extend.  So:

LaravelClass.php:

```
if(class_exists(Illuminate\Routing\Controller:class)){
  class LaravelClass extends Illuminate\Routing\Controller {
    use YourCodeTrait;

    // any more code that is not in your trait
  }
}
```

LumenClass.php

```
if(class_exists(Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller:class)){
  class LaravelClass extends Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller {
    use YourCodeTrait;

    // any more code that is not in your trait
  }
}
```

Loading both files will only load one of the classes.  In the code above I use a trait to load the contents of your controller, assuming the contents is the same, you could use the same trait and not have to repeat yourself.

```
trait YourCodeTrait{
  // whatever would normally go in your controllers
}
```

Comment: That would mean I have to code my controllers twice, one for each file?

Comment: No - write all your code in the trait, which you can use in each controller as shown above.  this will, in practice, import everything in your trait to your controllers.

Comment: I'm looking for something more elegant, something that's not 'hacky'. But thank you for your suggestion.